# js regex to clean all but digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have this...

```
sanitizeNumber = function ( dirtyNumber ){
    // remove any non-digits from the number
    return dirtyNumber.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
}
```

.. but it appears to be allowing decimal points through.

How can I remove absolutely everything except for the digits from 0 to 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud remove the `.` after the `\d`

```
sanitizeNumber = function ( dirtyNumber ){
    // remove any non-digits from the number
    return dirtyNumber.replace(/\D/g, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the `.` after `\d`

```
dirtyNumber.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

`/\D/g` grab every non digit char.
`\d` - A digit
`\D` - Not a digit

```
sanitizeNumber = function ( dirtyNumber ){
    // remove any non-digits from the number
    return dirtyNumber.replace(/\D/g, "");
}
```

Note that if you want to learn `regex` other options are:

```
return dirtyNumber.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
return dirtyNumber.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a great answer but I gave the points to jbduzan because he got his solution in slightly before you and also he could do with some points :)

Comment: @Xoundboy. Actually he answered 40 seconds after me.. `:)` doesn't matter.